# Uniform Type Identifier's used in Mac OS

Tags: macos, file

Is this file type identification mechanism the same as unix's magic number method ? OR are UTI's saved in the file system ?

Answer (score 0):

The system is aware of several common and public UTIs. Your app can also declare new UTIs via its bundle plist, or even programmatically/dynamically. It's system supported, and extends beyond the filesystem. UTIs are generally a materialization/representation of UTI hierarchies, file extensions, four character codes, and MIME types for a given type (e.g. `public.jpeg`).

Comment: are these meta data stored in the header ?

Comment: No. Although we often associate them with files, UTIs are not exclusively for files. Nor are they necessarily physical; A UTI may be entirely abstract, and inherit from multiple abstract bases.

Comment: How does MAC find a association between type and file then ?

Comment: often by matching the file extension with UTIs available on the system.